# Haskel: How can I merge an Int and [Int] into one (Int, [Int])?

Tags: haskell

I am a new guy to Haskell and today I have a problem with a question.

For example, I have an Int 10, an [Int] [1,2,3,4,5], how can I merge them together to [10,[1,2,3,4,5]]?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What would be the *type* of `[10,[1,2,3,4,5]]`?

Comment: Your question title and body have different questions: in the title you've written a tuple `(Int, [Int])` while the body has... something else. Which are you looking for?

Comment: You can have `(10, [1,2,3])` or `[[10], [1,2,3]]`, but not `[10, [1,2,3]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these may suit your needs:

```
(10, [1,2,3,4,5]) :: (Int, [Int])
10 : [1,2,3,4,5] :: [Int] -- = [10,1,2,3,4,5]
[Left 10, Right [1,2,3,4,5]] :: [Either Int [Int]]
[[10], [1,2,3,4,5]] :: [[Int]]
```